# Animated Zoom im a picture

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am trying to implement animations when zooming a picture - that is to make some frames and display them with a timer so it seems that the picture is mooving to the zoom area. The thing is that I dont have any idea how to do it.
Here is some code.

```
if (e.getSource() == timer) {
            currentFrame++;
            int newImageWidth =  ((mandel.getWidth() - selection.width) / frames) ;
            int newImageHeight = ((mandel.getHeight() - selection.height)/frames) ;
            BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(newImageWidth , newImageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
            g.scale(newImageWidth, newImageHeight);
            g.drawImage(mandelImage, 0, 0, mandel.getWidth(), mandel.getHeight(), null);
            g.dispose();
            mandelImage = resizedImage;//mandelimage is the original picture

            mandel.repaint();//the panel where is the picture

            if (currentFrame >= frames) {

                timer.stop();
                recreate();//the final result on the zoom

            }
```

Comment: Do you run it to specific problems? Or don't you know how to start at all?

Comment: Well I cannot find a proper tutorial on this. Currently it is making a small rectangle in the upper-left corner with the rest of the panel white and displays the dinal image.

Comment: When asking a question, you should add such important information like what is not working to the question. This will help you to get better answers more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation for the current image size needs to depend on the current time / progress of the animation. So if you do not use `currentFrame` in your calculation, the size will always be the same and you have no animation.

Specifically, you probably want something like this to scale the image from very small to full size over time:

```
int newImageWidth =  ((mandel.getWidth() - selection.width) * currentFrame/frames) ;
int newImageHeight = ((mandel.getHeight() - selection.height) * currentFrame/frames) ;
```